# User management for WSO2 IS Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 IS (5.10) and Analytics (5.8), on separate servers, following the WSO2 IS documentation.  I am successfully getting authentication events received into Analytics and can view them (after many headaches with IS insisting on using ports and SSL that I never told it to use - another story).

Now I can log into the dashboard, (/portal, admin/admin), and I see the IS events. Where do I manage portal users, permissions, and authentication?  I want to add additional viewers (via LDAP) but can't even find a place to change the admin password, never mind manage additional users.

Nor can I find any documentation on how to manager users in Analytics.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since Identity Server Analytics is also based on the WSO2 Stream Processor you can try out this. https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP440/User+Management

Comment: Thank you!  Maybe I can't do LDAP but at least I can change passwords and add users via the deployment.yaml.  Lots of other stuff there too that I was wondering how to configure like the worker passwords and the DB credentials.